Does a default interface implementation on a struct introduce boxing?
I am making a simple network messaging system, and I have designed it around using structs for any small messages (and I am trying to avoid boxing as much as possible). The system is already working, but I wanted to add a simple helper interface.
I have checked out similar posts on struct boxing, but I can't find information related to interface default implementations.
I have an interface that looks like this that I call with a generic function to avoid boxing. This works fine.:
public interface INetMessage
{
    public void OnServer(NetPeer peer, ServerManager server);
    public void OnClient(ClientManager client);
}

The new helper interface looks like this:
public interface IEntityUpdate : INetMessage
{
    public uint EntityID { get; init; }

    void INetMessage.OnServer(NetPeer peer, ServerManager server)
    {
        // Calls Update() method
    }
    void INetMessage.OnClient(ClientManager client)
    {
        // Calls Update() method
    }

    void Update(EntityData data);
}

and is implemented here:
public readonly record struct HealthUpdate(
    uint EntityID,
    uint Health
) : IEntityUpdate
{
    public void Update(EntityData data)
    {
        // update some data
    }
}

I have removed serialization attributes to make the code simpler.
Do I have to be concerned about the HealthUpdate struct being boxed whenever I call its OnServer() or OnClient() method?
My calling method is a generic method constrained with where T: INetMessage,where T is statically passed in as HealthUpdate, if that affects anything.

It's strange that it's just a "wart in the language". For now, I worked around it by using a static extension method and calling it in all the struct implementations (instead of using a default implementation). Thanks for the info!

see my answer in the other question. It will still allocate by default (maybe under some circumstances JIT will help)
